# Classes between PH and PSPACE

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes

I am interesting in languages of the following form:

$x \in L \Leftrightarrow Q y_1 Q y_2 \ldots Q y_n P(x, y_1, \ldots y_n, x).$

Here every Q is $\forall$ or $\exists$;

$n$ is the length of $x$,  the lengths of $y_i$ are bounded by poly($n$);

$P$ is a polynomial-time computable function.

Denote by $m$ the number of alternations in this expression.

If $m$ is constant then $L \in \text{PH}$; if $m=n-1$ then $L$ can be $\text{PSPACE}$-complete.

Consider some intermediate $m$, for example $m=O(\log n)$.

**Question:** Does anybody consider the class of corresponding languages
(for some $m = o(n))$)?

Is there some established name for it?

Comment: Search for $\mathsf{AltTime}(\lg n, n^{O(1)})$.

Comment: In some literature, it of also started as $\mathsf{ATimeAlt}(n^{O(1)}, \lg n)$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_Turing_machine

Answer (score 5):

The paper [Hyper-polynomial hierarchies and the polynomial jump](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0304-3975(00)00193-6) by Fenner, Homer, Pruim, and Schaefer seems to be relevant.

Answer (score 5):

Sure, versions of the polynomial hierarchy "with an unbounded number of alternations" can be found in the literature.

One paper that stands out in my memory:
https://lance.fortnow.com/papers/files/npvsnl.pdf